# Sorting associative array with specific requirements

Tags: php, arrays

I have following array created dynamically.

```
Array
(
 [1x2] => Array
    (
        [AWAY] => Array
            (
                [PL] => 1.6
                [Yield] => 19.4
                [YieldLS] => 19.4
                [Picks] => 8
                [Price] => 14.97
                [Stake] => 8
                [AvgStake] => 1
                [AvgOdd] => 1.87
            )

        [HOME] => Array
            (
                [PL] => 6.9
                [Yield] => 34.7
                [YieldLS] => 34.7
                [Picks] => 20
                [Price] => 38.25
                [Stake] => 20
                [AvgStake] => 1
                [AvgOdd] => 1.91
            )

        [DRAW] => Array
            (
                [PL] => 2.4
                [Yield] => 240
                [YieldLS] => 240
                [Picks] => 1
                [Price] => 3.4
                [Stake] => 1
                [AvgStake] => 1
                [AvgOdd] => 3.4
            )

        [TOTAL] => Array
            (
                [PL] => 10.9
                [Yield] => 294.1
                [YieldLS] => 294.1
                [Picks] => 29
                [Price] => 56.62
                [Stake] => 29
                [AvgStake] => 3
                [AvgOdd] => 7.18
            )

    )

[Asian Handicap] => Array
    (
        [HOME] => Array
            (
                [PL] => 41.9
                [Yield] => 9.3
                [YieldLS] => 9.3
                [Picks] => 448
                [Price] => 885.79
                [Stake] => 448
                [AvgStake] => 1
                [AvgOdd] => 1.98
            )

        [AWAY] => Array
            (
                [PL] => 31.3
                [Yield] => 7.1
                [YieldLS] => 7.1
                [Picks] => 439
                [Price] => 877.33
                [Stake] => 439
                [AvgStake] => 1
                [AvgOdd] => 2
            )

        [TOTAL] => Array
            (
                [PL] => 73.2
                [Yield] => 16.4
                [YieldLS] => 16.4
                [Picks] => 887
                [Price] => 1763.12
                [Stake] => 887
                [AvgStake] => 2
                [AvgOdd] => 3.98
            )

    )

[Over/Under] => Array
    (
        [OVER] => Array
            (
                [PL] => 14.7
                [Yield] => 10.1
                [YieldLS] => 10.1
                [Picks] => 145
                [Price] => 281.45
                [Stake] => 145
                [AvgStake] => 1
                [AvgOdd] => 1.94
            )

        [UNDER] => Array
            (
                [PL] => 14.1
                [Yield] => 19.5
                [YieldLS] => 19.5
                [Picks] => 72
                [Price] => 140.94
                [Stake] => 72
                [AvgStake] => 1
                [AvgOdd] => 1.96
            )

        [TOTAL] => Array
            (
                [PL] => 28.8
                [Yield] => 29.6
                [YieldLS] => 29.6
                [Picks] => 217
                [Price] => 422.39
                [Stake] => 217
                [AvgStake] => 2
                [AvgOdd] => 3.9
            )

    )
 )
```

What I want is to sort it according to specific requirements. For example I need output as

```
 Array
(
 [1x2] => Array
    (
        [HOME] => Array
            (
                [PL] => 6.9
                [Yield] => 34.7
                [YieldLS] => 34.7
                [Picks] => 20
                [Price] => 38.25
                [Stake] => 20
                [AvgStake] => 1
                [AvgOdd] => 1.91
            )

         [DRAW] => Array
            (
                [PL] => 2.4
                [Yield] => 240
                [YieldLS] => 240
                [Picks] => 1
                [Price] => 3.4
                [Stake] => 1
                [AvgStake] => 1
                [AvgOdd] => 3.4
            )

        [AWAY] => Array
            (
                [PL] => 1.6
                [Yield] => 19.4
                [YieldLS] => 19.4
                [Picks] => 8
                [Price] => 14.97
                [Stake] => 8
                [AvgStake] => 1
                [AvgOdd] => 1.87
            )



        [TOTAL] => Array
            (
                [PL] => 10.9
                [Yield] => 294.1
                [YieldLS] => 294.1
                [Picks] => 29
                [Price] => 56.62
                [Stake] => 29
                [AvgStake] => 3
                [AvgOdd] => 7.18
            )

    )

[Asian Handicap] => Array
    (
        [HOME] => Array
            (
                [PL] => 41.9
                [Yield] => 9.3
                [YieldLS] => 9.3
                [Picks] => 448
                [Price] => 885.79
                [Stake] => 448
                [AvgStake] => 1
                [AvgOdd] => 1.98
            )

        [AWAY] => Array
            (
                [PL] => 31.3
                [Yield] => 7.1
                [YieldLS] => 7.1
                [Picks] => 439
                [Price] => 877.33
                [Stake] => 439
                [AvgStake] => 1
                [AvgOdd] => 2
            )

        [TOTAL] => Array
            (
                [PL] => 73.2
                [Yield] => 16.4
                [YieldLS] => 16.4
                [Picks] => 887
                [Price] => 1763.12
                [Stake] => 887
                [AvgStake] => 2
                [AvgOdd] => 3.98
            )

    )

[Over/Under] => Array
    (
        [OVER] => Array
            (
                [PL] => 14.7
                [Yield] => 10.1
                [YieldLS] => 10.1
                [Picks] => 145
                [Price] => 281.45
                [Stake] => 145
                [AvgStake] => 1
                [AvgOdd] => 1.94
            )

        [UNDER] => Array
            (
                [PL] => 14.1
                [Yield] => 19.5
                [YieldLS] => 19.5
                [Picks] => 72
                [Price] => 140.94
                [Stake] => 72
                [AvgStake] => 1
                [AvgOdd] => 1.96
            )

        [TOTAL] => Array
            (
                [PL] => 28.8
                [Yield] => 29.6
                [YieldLS] => 29.6
                [Picks] => 217
                [Price] => 422.39
                [Stake] => 217
                [AvgStake] => 2
                [AvgOdd] => 3.9
            )

    )
 )
```

In first level `1x2` should be first item, then `Asian Handicap` and last `Over/Under`. Similarly in `1x2` and `Handicap` second level should be `Home, Draw, Away and Total`. In `Over/Under` second level be `Over then Under and then Total`. For any item/element missing, I need to add empty record/array. Numbers of `elements` and `keys` will always be fixed.

Missing case can be like this

```
 Array
(
 [1x2] => Array
    (
        [HOME] => Array
            (
                [PL] => ''
                [Yield] => ''
                [YieldLS] => ''
                [Picks] => ''
                [Price] => ''
                [Stake] => ''
                [AvgStake] => ''
                [AvgOdd] => ''
            )

         [DRAW] => Array
            (
                [PL] => 2.4
                [Yield] => 240
                [YieldLS] => 240
                [Picks] => 1
                [Price] => 3.4
                [Stake] => 1
                [AvgStake] => 1
                [AvgOdd] => 3.4
            )

        [AWAY] => Array
            (
                [PL] => 1.6
                [Yield] => 19.4
                [YieldLS] => 19.4
                [Picks] => 8
                [Price] => 14.97
                [Stake] => 8
                [AvgStake] => 1
                [AvgOdd] => 1.87
            )



        [TOTAL] => Array
            (
                [PL] => 10.9
                [Yield] => 294.1
                [YieldLS] => 294.1
                [Picks] => 29
                [Price] => 56.62
                [Stake] => 29
                [AvgStake] => 3
                [AvgOdd] => 7.18
            )

    )

[Asian Handicap] => Array
    (
        [HOME] => Array
            (
                [PL] => 41.9
                [Yield] => 9.3
                [YieldLS] => 9.3
                [Picks] => 448
                [Price] => 885.79
                [Stake] => 448
                [AvgStake] => 1
                [AvgOdd] => 1.98
            )

        [AWAY] => Array
            (
                [PL] => ''
                [Yield] => ''
                [YieldLS] => ''
                [Picks] => ''
                [Price] => ''
                [Stake] => ''
                [AvgStake] => ''
                [AvgOdd] => ''
            )

        [TOTAL] => Array
            (
                [PL] => 73.2
                [Yield] => 16.4
                [YieldLS] => 16.4
                [Picks] => 887
                [Price] => 1763.12
                [Stake] => 887
                [AvgStake] => 2
                [AvgOdd] => 3.98
            )

    )

[Over/Under] => Array
    (
        [OVER] => Array
            (
                [PL] => 14.7
                [Yield] => 10.1
                [YieldLS] => 10.1
                [Picks] => 145
                [Price] => 281.45
                [Stake] => 145
                [AvgStake] => 1
                [AvgOdd] => 1.94
            )

        [UNDER] => Array
            (
                [PL] => 14.1
                [Yield] => 19.5
                [YieldLS] => 19.5
                [Picks] => 72
                [Price] => 140.94
                [Stake] => 72
                [AvgStake] => 1
                [AvgOdd] => 1.96
            )

        [TOTAL] => Array
            (
                [PL] => 28.8
                [Yield] => 29.6
                [YieldLS] => 29.6
                [Picks] => 217
                [Price] => 422.39
                [Stake] => 217
                [AvgStake] => 2
                [AvgOdd] => 3.9
            )

    )
 )
```

I have tried using separate array for sorting, but putting the logic of missing array and sorting at once made at complex. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd make a template array with empty records in the correct order then iterate over it and check the source array has the same associative elements.

If it exists and not empty, override the template item with the source.
If the template is in an order what you need, then at the end you have a template filled with data in the correct order and if you have blanks, that is filled with the template's empty data.

```
<?php
$sourceWrongOrder = [];


$emptyRecord = [
    'PL'       => '',
    'Yield'    => '',
    'YieldLS'  => '',
    'Picks'    => '',
    'Price'    => '',
    'Stake'    => '',
    'AvgStake' => '',
    'AvgOdd'   => '',
];

$template = [
    '1x2'            =>
        [
            'HOME'  => $emptyRecord,
            'AWAY'  => $emptyRecord,
            'TOTAL' => $emptyRecord,
        ],
    'Asian Handicap' =>
        [
            'HOME'  => $emptyRecord,
            'AWAY'  => $emptyRecord,
            'TOTAL' => $emptyRecord,
        ],
    'Over/Under'     =>
        [
            'OVER'  => $emptyRecord,
            'UNDER' => $emptyRecord,
            'TOTAL' => $emptyRecord,
        ]
];

foreach ($template as $name => &$items)
{
    foreach ($items as $title => &$item)
    {
        if (isset($sourceWrongOrder[$name][$title]))
        {
            $item = $sourceWrongOrder[$name][$title]
        }
    }
}
```

At the end your $template becames the right order filled with correct data.

Comment: Added some example code, but not tested, can you verify it please?

Comment: Let me try them.